# What proof is there that explains why the tangent lines of $x^2$ will eventually form $x^2$?

Tags: calculus

I have taken a lot of calculus recently, and am revisiting Calculus I: I know calculus is the study of change, specifically if the slope is changing. For example, if I have a car going x mph, and x is changing whether its accelerating or decelerating, how do I know that this will plot out a continuous graph? A more concrete question is, if I have a car accelerating to the formula $x^2$, and I have a whole bunch of tangent lines of $x^2$ at different intervals of $x$, how do I know that those tangent lines will eventually connect with each other to form the graph of $x^2$? What proofs is there?

Here is the tangent lines of $x^2$ at intervals $\frac{1}{4}$, $\frac{1}{2}$, $\frac{3}{4}$ and 1.
[image]

And, here is the tangent lines of $x^2$ at the intervals $\frac{1}{8}$, $\frac{1}{4}$, $\frac{3}{8}$, $\frac{1}{2}$, $\frac{5}{8}$, $\frac{3}{4}$, $\frac{7}{8}$, and 1.
[image]
How do I know these lines will eventually form $x^2$ without a gap between each line, as the $\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}$?

I'm sorry if this appears to be a very trivial question.

Comment: Visualize string art that you might have seen, in particular the curves that bound the empty space where the strings aren’t.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a corollary of Taylor's theorem with remainder term, we get:

> Suppose that $f$ is twice differentiable on $[a, b]$ and $|f''(x)| \le C$ for every $x \in [a,b]$.  Then whenever $x, x + \Delta x \in [a, b]$, we have
>   $$|f(x + \Delta x) - f(x) - f'(x) \Delta x| \le \frac{C}{2} (\Delta x)^2.$$

Now, the term $x + \Delta x \mapsto f(x) + f'(x) \Delta x$ is the equation of the tangent line to the graph of $f$ at $(x, f(x))$.  Therefore, if the maximum length of an interval in your $n$th tangent line approximation goes to 0 as $n \to \infty$, and if your function $f$ has a bounded second derivative on the overall interval of consideration, then your tangent line approximation functions will approach $f$ uniformly.

In fact, you can say a bit more: for example, if you use $n$ equal-length subintervals in the $n$th approximation, then the maximum error in the $n$th tangent line approximation is $O(\frac{1}{n^2})$.

Answer (score 1):

Your line segments are effectively an approximation of the slope field for the differential equation $f'(x)=2x$. The slope of the tangent line at $x$ is given by $2x$. So we seek to find a  function $f$ such that
$$
f'(x)=2x
$$
with $f(0)=0$. Clearly $f(x)=x^2$ fits the bill and is unique since if two functions have the same derivative, then they must vary by a constant.

Answer (score 0):

The point of the derivative of $f$ at $x=x_0$ is to approximate the function $f$ near $x_0$ using a straight line. In particular, the derivative is the number $M$ such that

$$f(x_0 + h) \approx f(x_0) + Mh$$

for "small $h$". Indeed, this is usually the *definition* of the derivative in more advanced treatments (as opposed to the limit of the [difference quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_quotient), which is likely what you have come across as the definition).

This is why we have things like "$\sin x \approx x$ for small $x$", since for small $h$, $\sin(x_0+h) \approx  \sin(x_0) + M h$, where $M$ is the derivative  at $x_0$. In the case of $x_0 = 0$, the derivative of $\sin$ is $\cos(0) = 1$, so that $\sin h = \sin(0+h) \approx \sin(0) + 1h = h$.

Thinking of the derivative in this way, it is clear why the tangent lines at each point "make up" the curve $y=x^2$, since each of them is a good approximation close to that point.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, the answer to your question is basically the definition of the derivative. In other words, if things does not work out as you described, you say that the derivative does *not* exist at that point. In order for us to be able to say that the derivative exists, the tip of the little line segment must converge to the function graph.

Note that to make this discussion completely precise you would need to be a bit careful about the positioning of the little line segments because in some situations the procedure leads to a one sided derivative.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple method for solving "ordinary differential equations" called [the Euler method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method) which does basically what you say: from the tangents it constructs the function itself (without even probing in). In fact, there are many, many such methods.

As to the proof, that depends a bit on the precise statement of the problem, but check out the wiki section on "global truncation error" of the Euler method.